# I don't know what to do next

Tags: python, arrays, date

I am making a program to tell you the day of the week when told the date. 
This is what I have got so far but I don't know how to continue.

```
print('Welcome to the Daygram, the program that tells you the day on any date.')
print('Enter the date in the following format: DD MM YYYY')

date_input = input(What is the date? (DD MM YYYY)')
date_array = date_input.split(' ')

date = date_array[0]
month = date_array[1]
year = date_array[2]
```

If anyone could help me so I could figure out what I need to do next.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question.

Comment: first of all, your code as-written will throw a SyntaxError. Fix that before asking for more help ;)

Comment: Question should be specific: what are you stuck on?

Comment: The next thing you should do is learn the difference between lists and arrays, after you fix the missing quote.

Comment: Also, Python 2 and 3 have major differences, so if you aren't sure whether the version matters, you should specify the version.

Comment: @Wooble, what's the difference (as relevant here)?

Comment: @leewangzhong: one is a python data type created by .split(), the other is found in a module OP isn't importing.

Comment: I never knew there was a module for C-arrays. But I think it shouldn't be corrected like that: lists in several languages refers to linked lists, while Python lists ARE basically dynamic pointer arrays. Do Python array.arrays have any non-esoteric use? (Any use as widespread as numpy, that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll help you with some parts, but most of this code should be a learning experience for you.

```
import datetime

# prompt here for the date
# put it into a datetime.datetime object named "day"
# this is the part of the code you need to type

day_array = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]

day_of_week = day_array[day.weekday()]
```

The `datetime` module should be your go-to when working with dates. It gives you a comprehensive object with a list of methods relating to time and date, which is EXACTLY what you're looking for. You initialize a `datetime` object using `datetime.datetime(YEAR,MONTH,DAY)` (where you fill in the year, month, and day). You can also set a time, but it's not necessary in your use case.

The datetime object has a method called `weekday` that returns a number (`0` through `6`) that represents which day of the week that day represents. I built an array `day_array` that maps each day to the index it represents (e.g., a Monday will return `0`, so `day_array[0] == "Monday"` and etc).

At this point, it's child's play. The hard part is going to be to prompt the user for a day and convert that into a datetime object. That I'll leave for you.